# reference point is missing in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm sorry if it sounds stupid but this problem is driving me insane! the reference point of my 3d object in unity is far away from the object (please see the link of the picture), I also noticed something strange that the anchor presets of is not showing in inspector, could this be the problem? can anybody please help? thanks!
http://s11.postimg.org/r8g8mlljn/stack.png

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

1. Drag the gameobject onto the base heirarchy (i.e don't make it a child object) and click the cog in top right -> Reset position and then move back as a child object.
2. Toggle from local position to global position or vice-versa at the top.
3. Make sure you aren't in debug mode